# SQL Database is locked?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 and DB browser for SQLite. My code:

```
def createuser(user,password,dbname):
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO login VALUES 
('{user}','{password}')".format(user=user, password=password)
    print sql_insert
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(sql_insert)
    # Save (commit) the changes
    conn.commit()
```

However I get the error that the database is locked. I don't know what to do as it was working yesterday. When I execute the SQL code in the database browser to display the values in the table 'login', which is where these values go, sometimes the values I enter in this program appear, and sometimes they don't. This is a bit from a longer code that will post below, however the error messages only refers to this function.

```
import sqlite3
DEBUG = True
# sets up database


def setup():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Practice.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE login
     (Username text, Password text )''')
    conn.commit()


# main function
def main(dbname, user, password, hummus):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Practice.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    if hummus == "newuser":
        print "Creating user {user}".format(user=user)
        createuser(user, password, dbname)
    else:
        print "Not running"
        pass


    # Create table
    # c.execute('''CREATE TABLE login
      #   (Username text, Password text )''')

    # Insert a row of data
    # c.execute("INSERT INTO username VALUES 
    # ('raw_input()','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")

# creates new user in table 'username'


# creates new user in table 'username'
def createuser(user,password,dbname):
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO login VALUES 
('{user}','{password}')".format(user=user, password=password)
    print sql_insert
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(sql_insert)
    # Save (commit) the changes
    conn.commit()

    # We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
    # Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be 
lost.
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #setup()
    #exit()
    if DEBUG:
        db = 'Practice.db'
        user = 'tim'
        password = 'massimo'
        pass_check = True
        main(db, user, password, 'newuser')

    else:
        db = 'Practice.db'
        user = raw_input('Enter username ')
        password = raw_input('Enter password ')
        pass_check = raw_input('verify password ')
        if not password == pass_check:
            print ('Passwords do not match. ')

        main(db, user, password, 'newuser')
        #conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        #conn.commit()
        #elif perform == ("login",'Login'):







        #main(db, user, password, action)
```

**EDIT**

Because I was running from a local host, the issue is that I had the data base open at the same time I was trying to add to it. DB Browser for SQLite blocks this.

Comment: Unrelated to your locking issue, but consider using [placeholders](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib2.html?highlight=placeholder#templating). String formatting values into SQL queries is a really bad practice.

Comment: shouldnt `('raw_input()','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")` be commented out? It contains a rogue double quote symbol that can be messing with your code.

Comment: @ChanceFinley I tried this, but I get the same issues.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Can you show me how that would work? I'm still a newbie to python SQL interaction.

Comment: @Massimo where is this Database located? Is it on a network or on a local pc

Comment: Please read the linked documentation, but the gist of it is: use ? as a placeholder for values (with sqlite). Don't add quotes or anything. Pass the values in a tuple as 2nd argument to `execute()`, for example `c.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES (?, ?)", (user, password))`.

Comment: @lijaEverila Still doesn't work, I get the same error message.